# "while" loop is not reading reading a variable's contents

Tags: bash, test

I have setup a little script to illustrate my problem.

I have set up a `while` loop that I would like to keep looping as long as `$output` is equal to `No screen session found`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo Stopping server...

output=$(screen -S tls -X eval 'stuff "stop\015"')

while [ "$output" = "No screen session found." ]
do 
        echo "$output"
        sleep 1
done

echo Server stopped!
```

When I run this script, it halts instantly:

```
Stopping server...
Server stopped!
```

Well ok, so I guess `$output` did not equal `No screen session found.`.

However if I switch out the `while` loop for an `until` loop like so:

```bash
until [ "$output" = "No screen session found." ]
```

I should expect that my loop will now start looping as `$output` is not equal to the string as we just saw. And while the loop does keep looping, the `echo $output` command I added reveals that the loop should in fact terminate!

```
Stopping server...
No screen session found.
No screen session found.
No screen session found.
No screen session found.
```

As `$output` **is equal to** `No screen session found.`!

What is going on? **Why does the `while` and `until` loop just ignore the contents of `$output`?**

Comment: There's a CR at the end of the `screen` output

Comment: Apart from your question: You assign your variable once and don't change it in the loop, so the loop will just run infinitely once entered – probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your script with `-x` to enable tracing, like

```
bash -x myscript.sh
```

You will see:

```
+ echo Stopping server...
Stopping server...
++ screen -S tls -X eval 'stuff "stop\015"'
' output='No screen session found.
' = 'No screen session found.' ']'
+ echo Server 'stopped!'
Server stopped!
```

As you can see, @muru was correct in their comment: there is a carriage return at the end of `$output`, so the string is failing to match.

Since you're using Bash, a simple solution is to use a wildcard in your match expression:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Stopping server...

output=$(screen -S tls -X eval 'stuff "stop\015"')

while [[ "$output" = "No screen session found."* ]]
do 
        echo "$output"
        sleep 1
done

echo Server stopped!
```

Running this produces:

```
Stopping server...
No screen session found.
No screen session found.
.
.
.
```

As @DonHolgo points out, at this point you have an infinite loop, so you'll need to fix that as well.

---

A better solution might be to look at the exit code from `screen` rather than trying to match the output. You can write something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Stopping server...

while ! screen -S tls -X eval 'stuff "date\015"'; do
  sleep 1
done

echo Server stopped!
```

If I start this when `screen` is not running and then start a session in another terminal, I see:

```
Stopping server...
No screen session found.
No screen session found.
Server stopped!
```

Comment: It's not a newline (the command substitution would remove that) but a carriage return (evident from how the single quotes appear at the start of the lines, overwriting the `+` that `set -x` outputs)

Comment: Hello, I have tried your suggesting of adding the * symbol after my string, however the error persists.

Comment: @Kuba0040, note that for that pattern match, you need `[[ .. ]]`, not `[ .. ]`. Or `case $output in "No screen session found."*) echo match;; esac`

Comment: @Kuba0040 try copying and pasting the code from this answer and seeing if it works as expected.

Comment: Hello, it unfortunetly still isn't working. Now when running the script I am presented with this error message:

/home/kubaroot/stop.sh: 7: [[: not found
No screen session found.

This output repeats forever with an until loop, and terminates instantly with a while loop.

Comment: Are you sure you're running the script using `bash`? Note that if you're on ubuntu or debian and you type `sh somescript.sh`, **you are not using bash**. Always use `bash somescript.sh` if you mean it, or make the script executable and run it as `./somescript.sh`.

Comment: You were right. I was using sh. Thank You very much for your help, all works perfectly now.